# Package acceptance validation error : Microsoft Edge extension

Tags: microsoft-edge, appx, microsoft-edge-extension, appxmanifest

I am getting this error:

> "Package acceptance validation error: com.microsoft.edge.extension is a reserved extension type. Your app does not have permission to use this extension type. To request permission, please use our extension submission form: https://aka.ms/extension-request"

As per the above mentioned link I already submitted my Edge Extension, and I got mail from devAccount, that "Your consumable extension is in the Store."

I am really get confused how I should submit my extension on the Windows Store